# Facing issue in trying to synchronize two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I was trying to synchronize to two threads, one printing "ping" and another printing "pong", to print something like "ping pong ping pong ping...." I wrote the following program to achieve this, but couldn't get the expected result. I wonder what mistake I'm making. Solutions for the same are available on the internet but I thought I should give it a try myself before looking for a readily available answer.

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
  String val = null;
  MyThread(String val) {
      this.val = val;
  }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            PingPong.pintMessage(val);
        }
    }
}

public class PingPong {
   static Integer turn = 1;

   public static void main(String args []) {
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread("ping"));
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread("pong"));
       t1.start();
       t2.start();

   }
   public static void pintMessage(String msg) {
       synchronized (turn) {
         if(turn==1) {
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+msg);
             turn=2;
         }
         else {
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+msg);
             turn = 1;
         }
    }
   }
}
```

Output :

```
Thread-0 ping
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-1 pong
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-0 ping
Thread-1 pong
```

Kindly advise what fundamental mistake I'm making here and if there is a better approach to achieve the same behaviour. Thanks !!

**After making suggested changes :**  I have tried to use thread communication using wait/notify but getting IllegalMonitorStateException. I guess I have used wait/notify on the object I am acquiring lock on(wait/notify used in synchronized context). Please help me understand the subtlety of the concept. Thnaks !

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
    String val = null;

    MyThread(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                PingPong.printMessage(val);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}

public class PingPong {
    static Integer turn = 1;

    public static void main(String args []) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread("ping"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread("pong"));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
    public static void printMessage(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (turn) {
            if(turn==1) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+msg);
                turn=2;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+msg);
                turn = 1;
            }
            turn.notifyAll();
            turn.wait();
        }
    }
}

Output :
Thread-0 ping
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Thread-1 pong
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at PingPong.printMessage(PingPong.java:40)
    at MyThread.run(PingPong.java:12)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: Hi Scary, I just edited the question to reflect the obtained output. Thanks !

Comment: `printMessage` doesn't guarantee that your ping thread will always have a turn number of 1 and pong has a turn number of 2. As far as the method is concerned the turn number is unrelated to the current thread executing. To get the desired output, you need to find a way to communicate between threads so that ping knows its turn

Comment: @conscells : It would be helpful if you could suggest a way to allow ping thread to know if it's turn only.

Comment: I didn't mention because you said you did not want a readily available answer. But you could look into thread signaling or blocking queues to make multiple threads cooperate. I would also recommend going through http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html.

Answer (score 3):

you got the concept of `synchonized` wrong.

The JVM ensures, that there is allways only on process executing the *synchronised* block, but it does not control the enqueing process, that means it only handles the calls in the order they try to call that block.

In your case: each thread has the chance to execute the loop multiple times before the JVM sets it to background for another thread to execute.

If you want to ensure a particular order you have to use `wait()` and `notify()`/`notifyAll()`:
([edit]: this code might not working correctly (not tested), it is just to demonstrate the principle...)

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{
  private Object other;
  public void setOther (MyThread other){
    this.other = other;

  }
  //no changes
       while(true){
            PingPong.pintMessage(val);
            notifyAll();
            other.wait();
        }

}

public static void pintMessage(String msg) {
    synchronized (turn) {
     // no changes
      // MyThread.semaphore.notifyAll();
 }
}
```

see here for mor information https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

In your `pintMessage` no matter what the value of `turn` is you will print something.